# .clone() remains unchanged?

Tags: jquery

So lets do this when the DOM is ready:

```
var parent_copy;  // global scope in this context

function preDeviceSetup() {  // only fired once - should be enough to set parent_copy
  parent_copy = $('.parent').clone(true);  // passes clone to var parent_copy;
}
```

I want to do this more than once after some event:

```
function listWrap(count) {
  $(parent_copy).replaceAll('.parent');
  //...
}
```

Is `parent_copy` going to still hold the original clone?  Throughout the script changes are made within the .parent element and I want it to be over written possibly more than once with the original.  Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, just going on 3 hours of sleep (which isn't enough).

Comment: i don't think so. it's not a "real time" clone so even if you change stuff there, that doesn't mean you'll be changing it everywhere. why not just call your list_wrap everytime?(and include the clone call htere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the $() around $(parent_copy) since it's already a jQuery-wrapped object via the clone() call.  Also, parent_copy will be moved into the document when being used as the source of the replaceAll, so you will need to call clone again, to avoid losing the original clone:

```
function list_wrap(count) {
  parent_copy.clone(true).replaceAll('.parent');
  //...
}
```

Comment: So every time parent_copy its placed into the DOM it empties it?  I guess that would explain the reason this only worked once.

Comment: update:  my brain is fried but I can go to bed now...  It worked.  Thanks.